# 3 images side by side with text above each one (2 words each, seperated by a line break), entire thing centered

Tags: html, css

Below is the relevant code. I have 3 images, which need to be centered above the middle of the page. Each button needs a label above it, which is 2 words, seperated by a line break (because the words are too long side by side). The entire thing needs to be centered and each button loads a page in the "contentArea" div tag through AJAX. I've tried textwrap and various float methods but I cant seem to get it to work the way it should. I can do this with a table in about 30 seconds but with HTML and CSS it seems to be very difficult.

```
<body>

    <div class = "header">
    Usefull Tools
    </div>

    <br><br><br><br><br>

        <div class = "titles">Measurement<br>Calculator</div>
        <br>
        <div class = "titles">Mortgate<br>Calculator</div>
        <br>
        <div class = "titles">Unknown<br>Tool</div>

        <div class = "button">
        <img id = "1" src = "images/Button_dark1.png" onmouseover="mouseOver(id)" 
            onmouseout = "mouseOut(id)" alt = "Button 1" width = "126" height = "128">

        <img id = "2" src = "images/Button_dark2.png" onmouseover="mouseOver(id)" 
            onmouseout = "mouseOut(id)" alt = "Button 2" width = "126" height = "128">

        <img id = "3" src = "images/Button_dark3.png" onmouseover="mouseOver(id)" 
            onmouseout = "mouseOut(id)" alt = "Button 3" width = "126" height = "128">

        </div>  

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div id = "contentArea"></div>

</body>
```

Here is the css file.

```
.center
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
font-size:18px;
}

.centerLeft 
{
margin-left:33%;
font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
}
.header
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
font-size: 36px;
font-weight:700;
}

.titles
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:6px;
text-align:center;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:500;
font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.button
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:6px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}

body
{
background-color:#faf8cb;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your CSS rules here or in a jsfiddle?

Comment: If you can do it in a table, do it in a table. Looks like a good use for a table for me (I know there is a lot of people that think different, but it's my opinion)

Comment: Well I dont have much in the way of CSS because it doesnt work. I will post what I have tonight when I get home.

Comment: No a table is not an option, this is a course on Advanced Web Technologies, a senior level 400 university course and there are many reasons why tables are no longer used for page layouts and its more than just an opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in one of the comments that you're doing a course on Advanced Web Technologies which wont let you use old-skool way of doing things ie. tables etc.

From what i can see, there is a fair bit of room for improvement in your HTML markup.

1. Try avoid using `<br />` for anything other than adding line breaks to your text. For layout level spacings ( for example, having a space between header and body content ) use padding or margins.

So, markup can be refactored to something like below:

```
<div class="header">Usefull Tools</div>

<div class="buttons-group">
    ... some content that we want to space out from header and footer ...
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```

The `.buttons-group` class styled as follows to have some spacing:

```
.buttons-group {
    margin:40px auto;
    width:570px;
}
```

Which will add `40px` margin above and below `buttons-group`

The benifit is now you can change spacings easily without having to add or remove breaks and it follows a good pattern of using CSS for styling and HTML for markup

1. Next you require to create a button that has a caption spaned accross two lines with an image below it.

Below markup will be more than enough:

```
<a href="#" class="button">
    <span>Measurement<br />Calculator</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/126x128&text=Measurement+Button+Image" />
</a>
```

.. And relevant CSS ..

```
.button {
     display:inline-block;   
     vertical-align:top;
     text-decoration:none;
     color:black;
     margin:0 30px;
}
```

The `display:inline-block` prperty is there to make sure the `button` class which is applied on an `a` tag understands `margin` values properly

Below is the complete HTML and CSS, that could be used acheive the desired layout:

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">Usefull Tools</div>

<div class="buttons-group">
    <a href="#" class="button">
        <span>Measurement<br />Calculator</span>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/126x128&text=Measurement+Button+Image" />
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="button">
        <span>Mortgate<br />Calculator</span>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/126x128&text=Mortgate+Calculator" />
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="button">
        <span>Unknown<br />Tool</span>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/126x128&text=Unknown+Tool" />
    </a>
</div>

<div id="content-area"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.buttons-group {
    text-align:center;
    margin:40px auto;
    min-width:570px;
}

.button {
    display:inline-block;   
    vertical-align:top;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    margin:0 30px;
}

.button span {
     display:block;
     margin-bottom:3px;
     text-align:center;
}

.button img {
    display:block;
}
```

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/4KGAC/4/

[These](https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-html) [Resourses](https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-css) may help you write better HTML and CSS

Good luck :)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks so much. Going to play around with that and make the rest of it look as good as this now.